# how to make a instance variable global

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables

i have fbid a instance variable in my app delegate i want to use it in every class in my whole application without using NSUSERDEFAULT .i want to use extern data type but i am not getting any thing how to declare extern variable and how to use please help ?

Comment: by using appDelegate method you can use..

Comment: You can't make instance variables 'global'. Please read a comprehensive C tutorial before messing up the terminology.

Comment: (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication] sharedApplication]delegate].fbid
make sure fbid is a property exposed in AppDelegate.h

Comment: ye it is property exposed  but i want to make this variable global and i can use this variable directly with the help of class object from other class.how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare property variable in your `Application Delegate`.

Than you can access that variable anywhere as

```
//To set value
AppDelegate *yourAppdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication] sharedApplication]delegate];
yourAppdelegate.yourStringVariable = @"";

//To get value 
AppDelegate *yourAppdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication] sharedApplication]delegate];
NSString *accessValue = yourAppdelegate.yourStringVariable;
```

**EDIT**

Let's say you have `MyViewController`

//Header file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
     NSString *classLevelProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *classLevelProperty;

@end
```

//Implementation file

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize classLevelProperty;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    AppDelegate *yourAppdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication] sharedApplication]delegate];
    classLevelProperty = yourAppdelegate.yourStringVariable;

     //Here above classLevelProperty is available through out the class. 
}
@end
```

This can be done in any view controller and that property value of yourStringVariable is available to any viewcontroller or any other class as above code.

Hope this clears. Leave comment if still not able to get it correctly.

Comment: here my variable is in app delegate if my variable is any where else other then app delegate and i want to use that value in different class globally what can i do.this is my question exactly.

Comment: Code I have written answers that question only. You can get application delegate instance using first statement in above code and access its property value using last statement in above code. You can write those lines anywhere in any view controller. You need to import application delegate header file accordingly. Hope this clears to you.

Comment: thank you .yes this is clear to me.but i want to make the variable global from any class and can use it at any class in my application.waiting for your help .thank you once again .

Comment: Please add your code what you have done and what you want to do. I will help accordingly.

Comment: interface mainviewViewController
{
 NSString *mystr;
}
property (retain)NSString *mystr,*value;
end
//In .m file
implementation mainviewViewController
synthesize mystr
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  //i am setting value here.
    mystr =@"rrrr";
     
}
i want to use this mystr in another view or class
#import "mainviewViewController.h"
interface textview : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *mylable;
}
end
//in .m file of textview class
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",mylable.text);
}
how can i use here that class mystr .

Comment: @JanakNirmal any other way without using appdelegate.

Comment: Yes, You can use singleton class for that. Look out for singleton in iOS, you will get plenty of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a property on first view and set it from the second view.

This requires that the second view has a reference to the first view.

example:

FirstView.h

```
@interface FirstView : UIView

{

    NSString *data;

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *data;
@end
```

FirstView.m

```
@implementation FirstView

// implement standard retain getter/setter for data:

@synthesize data;

@end

SecondView.m

@implementation SecondView

- (void)someMethod

 {

    // if "myFirstView" is a reference to a FirstView object, then

    // access its "data" object like this:

    NSString *firstViewData = myFirstView.data;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to know how to use `extern` keyword then this is how to use it.
Declared a variable in your `viewController.h` or `viewController.m` above `@interface`  file where you're assigning the value to it.

in `viewController.h` like this-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int value = 5;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

}
```

and you can also declared it in `viewController.m` declared it above `@implementation`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

int value = 5;

@implementation ViewController


@end
```

Then use `extern` key word in which class you want to get this variable.
in `secondViewController.h` class declared a variable like this -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondviewController : UIViewController{

}

extern int value;

@end
```

Now in `secondViewController.m` you will see that `value` contains `5`.

**For more detail about** `extern` **keyword see** [Using extern to Specify Linkage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: where to declare extern variable second view controller i declared above the interface below the #import but i am getting null value in second view.

Comment: declare a variable globally any where you want then give value to it and now in which class you want to access it in that .h class declared that variable with extern key word and here it will keep same value as what you assigned it.

Comment: But i am not getting the value doing same .i am getting null can you show me the code of declaring extern variable in 2nd class if you can.

Comment: I have edited my answer ... see now.

Comment: sorry i was doing same  previously, the result was null .i am getting value  by calling instance method of that class .but i want that value directly by declaring a global variable in every class.if you have anything then share.

Comment: `extern` keyword and global variable both are different things... this is about extern not about global variable.

Comment: OK thank you .now how can i make users fbid variable global .i need this thing because i want to use users Facebook id in every class once i get it in main view controller .

Comment: For this @jennis answer is okay ...

Comment: is there any other way  to make a variable global which is present in main view controller .@jennis answer is for the variable which is present in app delegate file.

Comment: in appdelegate declare your variable just below `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` now you can use this variable any where you want by importing the Appdelegate.h in your class.

Comment: sorry to say i am getting null value in other class..